# Why this Tensor product of fields is a field

Tags: ring-theory

Is it true that the ring $\mathbb{Q}[i]\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}[i]$ is a field ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have that $\mathbb{Q}(i)\cong\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1)$, therefore
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Q}(i)\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}(i)&\cong \mathbb{Q}(i)\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+1)\\
&\cong\mathbb{Q}(i)[x]/(x^2+1)\\
&=\mathbb{Q}(i)[x]/(x-i)(x+i)\\
&\cong\mathbb{Q}(i)[x]/(x-i)\times\mathbb{Q}(i)[x]/(x+i)\\
&\cong \mathbb{Q}(i)\times \mathbb{Q}(i)
\end{align*}$$
which is not a field because it has zero-divisors, e.g., $(1,0)\cdot(0,1)=(0,0)$.

Comment: In general, if $f \in K[x]$ and $L$ is a field extension of $K$, then $K[x]/(f) \otimes_K L = L[x]/(f)$ splits by CRT into the $L[x]/(f_i^{k_i})$ where $f = \prod_i f_i^{k_i}$ is the decomposition into irreducibles in  $L[x]$. For example, if $f$ splits over $L$ in $n$ distinct linear factors, we get $K[x]/(f) \otimes_K L \cong L^n$.

Comment: Thanks. What about $\mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{C}$?